# Low performance when trying to load many theme_settings via add_setting in the wordpress theme_customizer API

Tags: wordpress, performance, caching, wordpress-theming

I've got a performance problem in my theme. I like to add MANY functions to change colors, fonts and so on. In this way I need for every option a setting in the $wp_customize array. But adding one setting will take 0.004 - 0.005 seconds (recorded local and not on a webserver). Multiplied by 50-100+ add_settings will cost performance and time of page-loading. In this way I got a warning for "not answering scripts". Yes, I could extend the time allowed for scripts to take, but this won't solve my primary performance problem

Is there any posibility to store this settings in a file or database, so while reloading the page, not every setting have to be recreated? I didn't find a way to get all settings or to set them all at once. So I couldn't save it like the defaults for my theme_mods.

I just found the possibility to add on setting at time via add_setting( $id, $args). Are there any possibilities for caching or something like this?

Do you have any other suggestions getting a better performance by using many settings in my theme options?

Thank you

Comment: Either don't use customizer and instead create separate options page, without live preview, or just be careful what you're live changing (you can disable live change for some controls).

Comment: The life change isn't the problem. This is fast, after the page loaded. But I think I really have to clean up the customizer and move a lot of my settings to an separate options page. - But I'm hoping to find an other solution.